VS Code extension: open and focus newly created markdown cell
I am building a small VS Code extension which works with Jupyter notebooks.  I have a function that adds a new markdown cell containing some text to the currently active notebook.  However, the cell is created in a closed state, so the user has to double-click on it to be able to edit it.  I would like the cell to be open and to have focus with the cursor placed at the end of the initially inserted text, but a search through the API documentation and associated code samples has not found me any way to do this.  Am I missing something?
My current code is as follows:
let insert_hello = vscode.commands.registerCommand('nps.insertHello', async () => {
  const editor = vscode.window.activeNotebookEditor;
  const i = editor?.selection.start || 0;
  const currentNotebook = editor?.notebook;
  if (currentNotebook) {
   const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
   const h = 'Hello';
   let x = new vscode.NotebookCellData(vscode.NotebookCellKind.Markup, h, 'markdown');
   edit.set(currentNotebook.uri, [vscode.NotebookEdit.insertCells(i+1, [x])]);

   await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
   let range = new vscode.NotebookRange(i+1, i+2);
   editor.revealRange(range, vscode.NotebookEditorRevealType.Default); // No obvious effect
   editor.selection = range;  // No obvious effect
  }
});


